# Azure Deployment not picking up SSL certificates in repo

Tags: django, git, azure, ssl

I'm currently running a Django app on the Azure server. I have a MySQL database to access using SSL. The SSL certificates I need to access the server are physically in the repo and I got my Django settings file to point to these using a relative path.

I have Azure set up to do continuous deployment from BitBucket. Problem is, at the end of the deployment, it will copy over all the files EXCEPT for the .pem files that I need.

I have to manually copy over the certificates everytime I push a commit. The files are in static/certs/*.pem

Is there something wrong with Azure? Or BitBucket? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Anything put manually inside the static folder gets cleaned out by Azure during deployment.

Just don't put anything inside the static folder